# Not understanding how recursive lines are being executed

Tags: python, recursion

Here is my code which returns the change of amount>=24 in coins of 5 and 7 only. But one thing I don't understand is the sequence of the coins.append(5) line being executed. I know that python executes code line by line, so the previous line coins= change(amount-5) where the recursive call is made, if I run the main function for 34, it will be, coins = change(29). But the function is recalling itself here before going to the line coins.append(5). Then how is it actually appending 5 to the list returned by change(24) finally? Is it actually executing the line coins.append(5) before calling itself again for 29 from 34?

```
def change(amount):
  assert amount>=24, "Only amount>=24 is allowed"
  if amount == 24:
    return [5, 5, 7, 7]
  if amount == 25:
    return [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
  if amount == 26:
    return [5, 7, 7, 7]
  if amount == 27:
    return [5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
  coins= change(amount-5)
  coins.append(5)
  return coins

print(change(34))
```

Output: [5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5]

Comment: If you call it with 34, it will recursively call itself with 29, then recursively call itself with 24.  That invocation will return `[5, 5, 7, 7]`.  The caller will then append `5` and return the result, i.e. `[5, 5, 7, 7, 5]`.  Its caller will then append `5` and return the result, i.e. `[5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5]`.  It's very straightforward.

Comment: It's buggy though.  If called with 28, for example, it will recursively call itself with 23, then give an assertion failed error.  For 28, it should presumably return `[7, 7, 7, 7]`, which it will never do with the current logic.  You might want to add a special case for 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each layer of the function has its own independent `coins` variable - it's not shared between calls.

```
change(34)  
    call change(29)
        call change(24)
            return [5, 5, 7, 7]  
        append 5 to that 
        return [5, 5, 7, 7, 5]
    append 5 to that
    return [5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5]
```

you're missing a base case for either `23` or `28`, by the way. If I do `change(33)` I'll get an assertion error.

Comment: Could you better explain how your pseudocode works ?

Comment: @konoufo It is not "pseudo code" it is a "pseudo execution trace".

Comment: @Vatine Yeah you're 100% right. Brain fart. Probably a good reason they should explain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it works:

```
|34 passed in function
|34 is bigger than all the conditions
||_34-5 is passed in the function
|| |29 is bigger than all numbers
|| |_29-5 is passed in the function 
|| | |Condition matched - 24. 
|| | |[5,5,7,7] returned
||_ 5 is added to the list
|_ 5 is added to the list
```

So due to the recursion, there are layers found. And `.append()` adds the element at the end of the list.

And you get `[5,5,7,7,5,5]`